# Using Regex to match Arabic Text in R

Tags: regex, r, unicode, arabic

I'm trying match elements in character vector that contain specific Arabic phrases.

So Far I have:

```
   #load list of Arabic phrases 
   list.of.phrases <- read.table("arabic_phrases.txt")

   #look for the first phrase
   phrase1 <- arabic.text.vector[grepl(list.of.phrases[1],arabic.text.vector)]
```

Unfortunately, this approach or using raw Arabic text doesn't seem to return anything and I get this message:

```
   Error in `[[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, qname, value = 1) : 
   replacement has 1 row, data has 0
```

I know that I can match Arabic words using : [U0627-U06FF]+ as in:

```
   #look for all cells containing arabic
   arabic <-arabic.text.vector[grepl("[U0627-U06FF]+",arabic.text.vector)]
```

...
So far my approach is to convert the Arabic text to its Unicode point values and then use grep; however, I'm having trouble with the conversion.

Am I heading in the right direction or does anybody have another solution/approach?

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example.